# I want to simulate spacebar keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

If someone presses the Enter key I want to simulate as if he has pressed the space bar. I tried the below but it is not working. Pressing enter does nothing. Please help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var spacepress = $.Event("keypress", {
    keycode: 32,
    which: 32
  });
  $('input').on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('input').trigger(spacepress);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text'>
```

Comment: In other words, you want to insert a space when pressing enter or does the spacebar has another behavior?

Comment: If you want to add a space on enter press just append a `' '` to the existing value

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yeah that can help , thanks

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that is working but cursor is not moving , and because it is space , so does not appear on screen as well, so not a good solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `trigger` will fire off any event handlers assigned to a given event but it does not simulate hitting the actual button on the keyboard. You'll have to handle that yourself.

Here's one way of doing it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var spacepress = $.Event("keypress", {
    keycode: 32,
    which: 32
  });
  $('input').on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('input').trigger(spacepress);
    } else if (e.which === 32) {
      $(this).val($(this).val() + ' ');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text'>
```

Comment: why we need to use elseif

Comment: @beginner Because that's how I'm handling the space event. Again, you aren't actually simulating hitting the spacebar with trigger. That's impossible. Instead, you're sending out an event that *looks like* the user hit the spacebar. That `else if` section is handling the case where it appears as though the user is hitting the spacebar.

Comment: `if (e.which == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();$(this).val($(this).val() + ' ');`

Comment: @beginner You could do it that way if you wanted.